# adding criteria to elseif statement

Tags: php, mysql

Where am I going wrong in this function? I'm asking it to pull users that have a reminder date that is this year (which works alone) and if the type is equal to Email or Call (this part isn't working). Thank you!

```
elseif 

($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisyear' 
&&(isset($_GET['type'])
 && in_array($_GET['type'], array('Email', 'Call'))))
 {     
 $thisyear = date('Y-m-d');     
 $todotype = $_GET['type'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND YEAR(reminder) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND contacttodo.type = '".$todotype."' ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
 }
```

UPDATE: This returns no records and there are several with both 'call' and 'email'

```
 elseif 
($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisyear'   
&& (isset($_GET['type'])
&& in_array($_GET['type'], array('Email', 'Call'))))
{   
$thisyear = date('Y-m-d');     
$todotype = $_GET['type'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND YEAR(reminder) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND contacttodo.type = '".$todotype."' ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
}
```

Comment: so....no help with an answer or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from the question, including the missing opening bracket and the missing operator:

```
elseif( ($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisyear') 
    &&  isset($_GET['type'])
    &&  in_array($_GET['type'], array('Email', 'Call')))
{     
    /* … */
}
```

The error "unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND" results from the && after the elseif condition:

```
elseif($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisyear')    /* no statement here */

&& (isset($_GET['type']) /* some weird code, resulting in unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND */
```

UPDATE: "This only returns one record with type 'call'"

Maybe your emails haven't the reminder set to 'thisyear'. Try:

```
elseif( ($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisyear') 
    || ( isset($_GET['type']) && in_array($_GET['type'], array('Email', 'Call')) ) )
{     
    /* … */
}
```

Comment: I removed the "(" after `=='this year` but it's only returning 1 record.

Comment: Then your logic is faulty. From the above code, I can't mention what the desired output should be nor what the several variables (which are checked) contain as data.

Comment: this is just not returning any records. there are at least 10 that match the year and type. I'm not seeing what is wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an operator in between your first and second criterion. Try an `&&` or `||`.

```
elseif ($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisyear'
    && isset($_GET['type'])
    && in_array($_GET['type'], array('Email', 'Call'))
) {
    ...
}
```

**Update:** Fixed parenthesis, cleaned up whitespace.

Comment: …and an opening bracket after the `elseif`;

Comment: I thought that would do the trick and tried that too earlier with no luck. Still getting error "unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND in" edited mine above

Comment: @ feela - brackets are open after `&& in_array($_GET['type'], array('Email', 'Call')))  {`

Comment: @joshua76 ??? the first round one is missing above `elseif(/*conditions*/) {/*statements*/}` (I've added an answer now)

Comment: @feela - yes you are correct, in my code above you will see I have one there. However, this still returns an error.

Comment: What I see above is an elseif-condition, which is finished after `'thisyear')`, so everything else in your example doesn't belong to the condition; [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

Comment: I fixed the parenthesis and whitespace to make it more understandable.

Comment: @ sirlancelot - thanks, doesn't return any records. see updated code above.